# Spring scheduled task to run separate threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have 4 jobs scheduled in my spring boot application using @Scheduled notation. Problem is that I want to run them on different threads and also put a time out on each scheduled job execution, if that job doesn't complete within given time, kill that job and execute next instance

The way I have implemented this in following way

**MAIN CLASS:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableCaching
@EnableJms
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT50S")
@ComponentScan
public class mainApplication {
.......

@Bean
public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource, "shedlock");
}
}
```

**JOB FILE:**

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/59 * * * ?")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "task_1", lockAtLeastFor = "PT120S", lockAtMostFor = "PT600S")
    public void periodicTask() throws Exception {
    //Execution code
    }
```

Similar to this periodicTask() I have 3 different tasks running. Currently all of these run on same thread. How do I make them run on different threads and also put a timeout on each tasks.

Comment: do you want to run all there jobs at same time asynchronously or synchronously? or at different time ?

Comment: Asynchronously is fine, they are unrelated jobs

Comment: You can add `@Async` to your `periodicTask()` and `@EnableAsync` on your application entrypoint to kick off these tasks concurrently.  I also want to warn you, playing with concurrent timeouts and locks can bring up some unintended consequences.